# Getting original object from Entity Framework SaveChanges function?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

For auditing reasons I am overriding the SaveChanges function. However, I want to capture to original and current values as the original object (i.e person) so that I can serialize both the before and after.

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer

    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
    Dim ctx As ObjectContext = DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext

    Dim objectStateEntryList As List(Of ObjectStateEntry) = ctx.ObjectStateManager.
        GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added Or EntityState.Modified Or EntityState.Deleted).ToList()

    For Each ent As ObjectStateEntry In objectStateEntryList
        If Not ent.IsRelationship Then
            Dim objectType As Type = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(ent.Entity.GetType)
            Dim audit As New Audit With {
                .ObjectId = ent.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.First.Value,
                .ObjectType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(ent.Entity.GetType).Name,
                .User = (From u In Users Where u.Username = My.User.Name).First
            }
            With audit
                Select Case ent.State
                    Case EntityState.Added
                        .Action = "Created"
                        .Detail = "Record created"
                    Case EntityState.Deleted
                        .Action = "Deleted"
                        .Detail = "Record deleted"
                    Case EntityState.Modified
                        Dim newObj As String = SerializeToString(
                            Convert.ChangeType(ent.Entity, objectType)
                        )
                        .Action = "Modified"
                        .Detail = newObj.ToString
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()

End Function
```

That's how far I got, but when I try and ChangeType it throws "Object must implement IConvertible".

Comment: What is SerializeToString and why does it care about the type you pass to it? Also, why not use JSON.NET for your serializer?

Comment: @JonathanAllen It's just a function I wrote which uses XmlSerializer and then returns the xml as a string so I can store it. I'm not using JSON.NET because I want to store it as XML.

Comment: Ah yes, that old problem. I see now why you want the call to ChangeType, though it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library. It does exactly what you want and can be configured to serialize and save the events as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I worked on a project that absolutely needed to track every change, we used a history table and an ON UPDATE trigger. Changing data would fire the trigger, which would then copy the original row into the history table.

This is 100% EF compatible, but you need to set it up separately for each table.

Comment: Makes sense, the schema for this project is very large though so it probably wouldn't be the best idea. My idea to get around that was to serialize the object and store that so that you only need a singular table. I can't believe it's so hard to retrieve the object as the original type during the SaveChanges() function.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your main question but may help you to improve your auditing.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

I recommend you to look at our [EF+ Audit Feature](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit), all auditing information can be easily retrieved using this library.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

var ctx = new EntityContext();
// ... ctx changes ...

var audit = new Audit();
audit.CreatedBy = "ZZZ Projects"; // Optional
ctx.SaveChanges(audit);

// Access to all auditing information
var entries = audit.Entries;
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    foreach(var property in entry.Properties)
    {
    }
}


// CALL your serializer here
SerializeToString(entries, ...);
```

The code is Open Source.